# jqgrid datepicker change date dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I need to change minDate and maxDate in datepicker in cell, base on value on other cell, so I have:

```
                    label: 'Start date',
                    name: 'startdate',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "text",
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                id: 'startDate_datePicker',
                                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                                minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                showOn: 'focus'
                            });
                        },
                    }
```

And dataEvent in other cell:

```
                            dataEvents: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'change',
                                        fn: function (e) {
                                            if ($(e.target).val() != null) {
                                                var val = $(e.target).val()
                                                var rowid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                              //CODE THERE
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                        ]
```

But I cannot find my datePicker:
$( "#startDate_datePicker" ) - is null.
How i can find this element in jqgrid row?

Comment: It was an error in my code. If you want to change option of datepicker you must use:  `$("#" + rowid + "_startDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(2017, 1 - 1, 1)); `

Comment: The id depend on editing mode which will be used. It seems that you use inline editing.